# Element Replace - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, dictionary, hashtable

I am trying to create a new array where elements of the original array are replaced with their corresponding values in the hash. I want to compare every element in arr to the key in hash and if they are equal shovel them into the arr and return it at the end. Why is my code not working and how can I access/return the key value of the respective entry in hash, not only the value pointed to by the key? If you get what I am saying.

```
def element_replace(arr, hash)
  count = []
    
  
  for i in arr do
    if i == hash.key
     count << value
    else 
      count << i 
    end
  end
   
  return count

end

arr1 = ["LeBron James", "Lionel Messi", "Serena Williams"]
hash1 = {"Serena Williams"=>"tennis", "LeBron James"=>"basketball"}
print element_replace(arr1, hash1) # => ["basketball", "Lionel Messi", "tennis"]
puts

arr2 = ["dog", "cat", "mouse"]
hash2 = {"dog"=>"bork", "cat"=>"meow", "duck"=>"quack"}
print element_replace(arr2, hash2) # => ["bork", "meow", "mouse"]
puts
```

Comment: Another way: `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = k }.merge(hash1).values_at(*arr1) #=> ["basketball", "Lionel Messi", "tennis"]`.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because `hash.key` returns the key of the first key-value pair. You want to `hash.has_key?(i)`. Also `value` isn't initialized and just `nil`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby's [`Hash::fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) would be a technique to get your desired result:

```rb
> players = ["LeBron James", "Lionel Messi", "Serena Williams"]
=> ["LeBron James", "Lionel Messi", "Serena Williams"]
> sports_data = {"Serena Williams"=>"tennis", "LeBron James"=>"basketball"}
=> {"Serena Williams"=>"tennis", "LeBron James"=>"basketball"}
> players.map { |player| sports_data.fetch(player, player) }
=> ["basketball", "Lionel Messi", "tennis"]
```

Comment: There are so many functions to learn in Ruby. The first programming language I learned was C/C++ so while these functions seem like a God send I am still getting use to the "Ruby way".

Answer (score 4):

You can [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-map) the array to hash keys or keep the array element itself: if the key is missing (return `nil`) keep the array element:

```
arr1.map { |k| hash1[k] || k }
#=> ["basketball", "Lionel Messi", "tennis"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your hash is supposed to return the key by default, you could use a [`default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Hash.html#default_proc-3D-method):

```
hash = { 'Serena Williams' => 'tennis', 'LeBron James' => 'basketball' }
hash.default_proc = proc { |hash, key| key }
```

Which gives you:

```
hash['LeBron James'] #=> "basketball"    # explicit value
hash['Lionel Messi'] #=> "Lionel Messi"  # default value
```

or, using an array:

```
arr = ['LeBron James', 'Lionel Messi', 'Serena Williams']

hash.values_at(*arr)
#=> ["basketball", "Lionel Messi", "tennis"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def element_replace(arr, hash)
  new_arr = []
  arr.each { |n|
   if hash.has_key?(n) 
     new_arr << hash[n]
   else 
     new_arr << n 
     
   end 

  }

  
  return new_arr
 end 







arr1 = ["LeBron James", "Lionel Messi", "Serena Williams"]
hash1 = {"Serena Williams"=>"tennis", "LeBron James"=>"basketball"}
print element_replace(arr1, hash1) # => ["basketball", "Lionel Messi", "tennis"]
puts

arr2 = ["dog", "cat", "mouse"]
hash2 = {"dog"=>"bork", "cat"=>"meow", "duck"=>"quack"}
print element_replace(arr2, hash2) # => ["bork", "meow", "mouse"]
puts
```

Comment: Is this… an answer? A clarification of the requirements? Final code after applying the accepted answer? Right now it's unclear. Can you [edit] your answer to tell us what this is and why you're posting it as an answer?

Comment: Yes it is my solution. I found a way for it to work so I posted the code that made it work.